# Which way is better to send data by POST method in objective-C?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, sqlite, data-migration

I am moving data from sqlite to webserver (mySql), from iphone to web and php will be landing site which insert data in mysql after getting data in POST format.

I am using **NSURLConnection** in iOS. I am confused how to move data, so I figured out that I should append all the data in string from a table seperated by comma and `\n` for row. Since data consist complete postal address(name, address, phone, email) and maximum record might be 500, don't know if there are other better ways.

My options are:

1. Send each line of row after reading data from table
2. Sending whole data in one single variable(string)
3. I don't know.

Please suggest me.

Comment: or send an array of information?

Comment: yeah, I though that too, but could not figure out what different between sending in array and sending as a single string, cause logically I thought they will occupy same memory space, if I send a big string or send a big array.

Comment: consider that sending it line-by-line will involve multiple http requests and the http overhead will quickly outweigh any "savings" from bulking up the data. you'll have to figure out an appropriate balance between requests v.s. data body size

Comment: I got comment about this part too, one of my friend suggested that because of rapid 'http' response all or none data may be stored, or loss(some) of data may occur.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend POST method and because POST has no limit of characters you can do the whole database to your mysql.

I should make in PHPmyAdmin (or something similar) an export or an backup and send that to your mysql.

Comment: Actually I am asking question for iOS, and better method to send data